How to stop Windows from changing date modified when copying files from network?
Since the release of KB5039212 on June 11, 2024 the modification date of files changes when copied from a network for example from a network attached storage (NAS) with Windows File Explorer.
This problem was reported for example by Lui Lui the 3rd and Janus Ch.
This is a serious problem as it will destroy date information and stop backup software from working.
So how can the modification date be preserved?

As discussed at Jose Santiago_329 the reason is that

Starting in this update, File Explorer adds the Mark of the Web (MoTW) tag to files and folders that come from untrusted locations. When MapUrlToZone classifies a file as “Internet,” that file also gets this tag. Because of this change, the “LastWriteTime” time stamp is updated. This might affect some scenarios that rely on file copy operations.

Making the site trusted works around this problem as explained by Ramesh Srinivasan (IA):

This might be a bug in the recent Windows 11 builds. However, there is a workaround. To prevent the ADS from being written, you can add the computer name that hosts the network share to the Local Intranet zone in IE Options.

To open IE Options, run "inetcpl.cpl".

Click on the "Security" tab, and click "Local Intranet".

Click "Sites", and click "Advanced".

Add the computer name or the IP address you use to access the computer that hosts the network share to the list.

Click OK, OK, to save your settings.

Please also report this bug through the Windows Feedback Hub to Microsoft and ask for a fix.

Windows 11 still uses the ancient IE Options? Yikes!

I'm suspecting this is really a bug, since it's the same Explorer that applies the original timestamp to the copied file in the first place, so surely they could've just made it apply the MOTW before applying timestamps instead of after... but I guess they were in a hurry.

@EndAntisemiticHate If it ain't borked, don't fix it?
